# Is it correct to refer to two different sources using "this" and "this"? If false what synonyms could be used?

Tags: synonyms, syntactic-analysis

Is the following decent English:

> Based on sources like this and this the following code was created:

If it is correct English? What kind of synonym could be used in this context?

Comment: You could always switch to *like this and **that***. But always remember, [***This is this and that is that!***](http://www.searchquotes.com/quotation/This_is_this_and_that_is_that!_-Flownder/266680/) Seriously, just say *Based on sources like **these*** (or ***those***, as you feel fit) or don't bother repeating the word (***this*** can apply to multiple referents simultaneously).

Comment: Almost certainly "this" and "this" were hyperlinks in the original sentence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recursive referencing may be confusing and should be avoided. It would be best practice if you say or write:

> Based on sources from StackExchange and Wikipedia the following code was created:

You could further on refer to StackExchange as "initial" and Wikipedia as the "latter":

> The *initial* reference points out.... where as the *latter* argues...

Answer (score 2):

In spoken English, this (excuse the pun) should be perfectly fine.

> Like a salesman showing you a couple of items in answer to your
>   inquiry and saying something like, "you should consider *this*, and
>   *this*".

I have seen such usage (even more than 2 instances of *this*) in online content when both/all instances are hyperlinked (to different web pages) and it looked perfectly fine.

> **Example**: A couple of definitions of *this* are [this](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/this) and
>   [this](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/this).

I guess it is a written analogue of the speech example I gave earlier.

Of course, such usage may not make sense in *printed* (or *handwritten*) text.

An alternative method in case of online content is to replace "*this and this*" with "*these*" (as already suggested by FumbleFingers) and then hyperlinking the word *these* to a location (a *footnote* or something similar) listing all your sources. It can be the same in printed text, except that you will replace hyperlinking with a reference to a *footnote* or *endnote*.